# JavaFX WebView not playing YouTube video properly

Tags: java, javafx, webview, youtube-api

I have JavaFX WebView set up to play YouTube videos using a URL, the issue I am running into is that certain YouTube videos prompt the message:
"This video contains content from (VEVO/UMG, etc). It is restricted from playback on certain sites."

Though when testing using an iFrame with the same video, the same video will play fine without the message which I ran into with JavaFX WebView. (You can test the iFrame on: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe)

For example, in the following iFrame the video will play fine though the same URL on WebView would result in the previously listed message.

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="390" 
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Ri7-vnrJD3k?autoplay=1&origin=http//example.com" 
frameborder="0"/>
```

This leads me to believe the issue has to do with the way WebView is getting the video from YouTube, would there be any way to get the behavior of WebView to work like that of the iFrame?

I have for now just embedded the full web page as I have attempted multiple methods to get the /embed/ url working though I have not been able to. I believe it may have to do with the origin parameter though I am not sure.

Comment: At a minimum use the [Java 8u72 early access version](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html) for youtube playback.  This was suggested by a comment on [gdata Issue 6589: Unable to start video in JavaFX WebView](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6589).  I could not get youtube videos to play back at all on Java 8u60 on OS X, but they worked fine once I upgrade to 8u72ea.  This will not aid in playback of the particular video you reference in your question, but will help for some other videos.

Comment: Java 8u72 will allow playback of videos which are not "restricted from playback on certain sites".  As you are playing back a video which is somehow restricted, I don't have advice on how to get that particular video to work as I don't know how the video playback restriction is enforced by youtube and why playback via WebView is restricted but not via other browsers.

Comment: @jewelsea Thanks for the tip, though I am currently running Java 8u72, my main issue is videos will play though there are certain cases where they won't play in WebView but will play when testing with the iFrame (usually videos off VEVO/UMG channels). I have attempted to narrow down the issue and I believe it may have to do with the origin component though haven't had much luck with it. EDIT: Just saw your second comment, you covered some of what I wrote in this comment.